# Get the logged in user in VirtualPathProvider class

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-identity

I have build a VirtualPathProvider who handle the request and get the data from data base.
and I am using asp identity 2013 to handle the authorization. 
Now I want to apply asp identity for this pages (DB pages).
My question is how can i access to Logged in User in VirtualPathProvider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the soulution for this. buy define an page instance e.g:

```
 System.Web.UI.Page webPage = new System.Web.UI.Page(); 
if(webPage.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) { }
```